# KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle and Google PHP API

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I have a Symfony 5 Application that is authenticating users by their Google account using KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle.

I now want to integrate the Google Drive API so the user can upload files to his Drive.

https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php
is giving some documentation about that.

What I am wondering: If the user is already authenticated (I have a valid user access token), do I have to run through the whole authentication process again or can I use the authentication token that was generated by KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle? And how do I get this authentication token as an object? When I am trying to get it via $client->getAccessToken() I get the error "Invalid State".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Yes, you can use the existing login token to authenticate with further services like Google Drive API. You just need the existing login token as a string.

Be aware that you might have to add additional scopes to the login like this:

```
$clientRegistry
        ->getClient('google_main') // key used in config/packages/knpu_oauth2_client.yaml
        ->redirect([
            'email',
            'profile', // the scopes you want to access
            Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_FILE,
        ], []);
```

Then in your Google Drive Service you can initiate the Client like this:

```
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
protected function initClient()
{
    $user = $this->security->getUser();
    $googleAccessToken = $user->getGoogleAccessToken();

    $this->client->setApplicationName('MY APPLICATION');
    $this->client->setScopes(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);
    $this->client->setAccessType('offline');
    $this->client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    $googleToken = [
        'access_token' => $googleAccessToken,
        'id_token' => $googleAccessToken,
        // user is having a valid token from the login already
        'created' => time() - 3600,
        'expires_in' => 3600,
    ];

    $this->client->setAccessToken($googleToken);

    return $this->client;
}
```